# Integrated webcam stopped working and now only show black screen

Tags: drivers, video, webcam, acer

I have a Acer Aspire A515-51-36VK and my integrated webcam stopped working recently.
Now every test only shows a black screen.

Here some test that I have made:

I found the webcam with `lsusb` (**[0408:a060](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:0408-a060) Quanta Computer, Inc.**):

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0408:a060 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

With the `ls -ltrh /dev/video*` I found the webcam too:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 ago 12 12:05 /dev/video0
```

When I run `dmesg | grep "video"`:

```
[   10.568524] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   10.701922] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD WebCam (0408:a060)
[   10.703435] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[   10.703436] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   10.703437] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   10.703753] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvid
```

And when I test the webcam with `guvcview`:

```
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.5
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I try many things, include format the system, and nothing change.

Have something that I can do to fix this problem?